# Displaying animated image

Tags: perl, perltk

```
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::Animation;

my $scr = new MainWindow;

$scr->configure(-background=>"black");
$scr->geometry("200x100");

my $canvas = $scr->Canvas(-width,200,-height,100,-background=>"black")
                 ->pack(-expand,1,-fill,'both');

my $image  = $scr->Animation('-format' => 'gif', -file=>"help.gif" );

$canvas->createImage( 50,50, -image=> $image);
$image->start_animation(500);

MainLoop;
```

I want the image to move up and down in my window.Now what should i add more in this code??

Answer (score 0):

Tk::Animation is only responsible for the animation of the Gif file. Animation in this case means, changing the frames all the times. The movement is thus restricted to the image content itself.

If you want to move the image as a whole on your canvas, you have to use the move method. Of course, this can be combined with a gif animation.

Here is an example with a gif moving from left to right:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::Animation;

my $mw = MainWindow->new();
$mw->configure(-background=>"black");
$mw->geometry("200x100");

my $canvas = $mw->Canvas(
    -width => 200,
    -height => 100,
    -background => 'black',
)->pack(
    -expand => 1,
    -fill => 'both',
);

my $image  = $mw->Animation(
    -format => 'gif',
    -file => 'oi.gif',
    # please use this one: http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/vaultarmory/images/2/23/Gif_dancinggir.gif
);

# -- clear transparent background while drawing
$image->set_disposal_method( 1 );

my $id_of_image_in_canvas = $canvas->createImage(
    50, 50,
    -image=> $image,
);
$image->start_animation(80);

# -- store the current mving direction
my $direction = 'moving2left';
$mw->repeat(600, \&move_item_in_canvas);

$mw->MainLoop();
exit(0);


sub move_item_in_canvas {
    # -- get current location
    my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = $canvas->bbox($id_of_image_in_canvas);

    # -- compute if to move left or right
    my $min_left = 0;
    my $max_right = 200;
    if( $direction eq 'moving2left' && $x1 > $min_left ) {
        # continue moving left
        $canvas->move($id_of_image_in_canvas, -10, 0);

    }elsif( $direction eq 'moving2left' && $x1 <= $min_left ) {
        # change direction, move to the right
        $direction = 'moving2right';
        $canvas->move($id_of_image_in_canvas, 10, 0);

    }elsif( $direction eq 'moving2right' && $x2 < $max_right ) {
        # move right
        $canvas->move($id_of_image_in_canvas, 10, 0);

    }elsif( $direction eq 'moving2right' && $x2 >= $max_right ){
        # change direction, move to the left
        $direction = 'moving2left';
        $canvas->move($id_of_image_in_canvas, -10, 0);

    }else{
        die('Error: don\'t know what to do in this case.');
    }

    return;
} # /move_item_in_canvas
```